# Как удалить лишнее расширение с файла?

Tags: c#

Имеется файл: name.txt.txt и файл name2.txt.

Пытаюсь с помощью `Path.ChangeExtension();` изменить расширение на .bat

Но после замены получаются такие файлы:

name.bat.bat, name2.bat

Вопрос как убрать второе расширение с файла если оно есть?!

Comment: `Path.ChangeExtension("name.txt.txt", "bat")` возвращает `name.txt.bat`, т. е. работает как и должно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static string ClearExtension(string file)
        => string.Join(".", file.Split('.').Take(2));
```

Проверяем:

```
Console.WriteLine(ClearExtension("file.txt.txt.txt"));
Console.WriteLine(ClearExtension("file.txt.txt"));
Console.WriteLine(ClearExtension("file.txt"));
Console.WriteLine(ClearExtension("file"));
```

```
file.txt
file.txt
file.txt
file
```

---

Можно пойти таким путем:

```
public static string ClearExtension(string file)
    => string.Join(".", file.Split('.').Distinct());
```

Данный вариант просто удалит все повторы и тут есть свои недостатки. Например `file.txt.log` не изменится, ибо нету дублей, или `127.0.0.1.log.log` выдаст `127.0.1.log` (удалил лишнее).

Поэтому мне кажется, что надо знать какую то отправную точку, например выписать все доступные расширения файлов в некий массив, так программа будет почти четко различать имя от расширения.

Примерно что то в этом духе:

```
private static string[] Extensions = { ".txt", ".log", ".bin", ".bat" };
public static string ClearExtension(string file)
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
    var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
    var arr = Regex.Split(fileName.ToLower(), @"(?=[.])");
    var extension = arr.Last(x => Extensions.Contains(x));
    var name = string.Join(null, arr.Where(x => !Extensions.Contains(x)));
    return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dir) ? dir + "\\" + name + extension : name + extension;
}
```

Тогда `127.0.0.1.bat.log` успешно переведется в `127.0.0.1.log`.
Или `C:\\MS.NET\\1.1.1.1.2.txt.log.bat.bin.log` выдаст `C:\MS.NET\1.1.1.1.2.log`

Comment: Работает, но если файлов много, то в некоторых даже удаляется первое расширение =)

Comment: @Anonymous Хм, название с точкой? Если да, то можете показать его?

Comment: @Anonymous Я дополнил ответ с решением, скажем так... "в лоб", на 99% должно решить задачу, если у вас конечно нету файлов с именами `name.txt.custom.bat`...

Comment: А варианты типа `C:\MS.NET\1.TXT` как обрабатываются?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я изначально работал чисто с название файла, думая что путь ранее уже был отсечен. Ну если путь имеется, то смело можно разделить, не беда. Изменил последний вариант и успешно теперь все отрабатывает.

Comment: Ок. В любом случае, при наличии готового api в стандартной библиотеке, делать это всё "вручную", мне кажется неправильным.

Answer (score 2):

С путями следует работать с помощью соответствующего встроенного в стандартную библиотеку API. Например, для удаления "многозначного" расширения файла можно написать что-то вроде:

```
public static string ClearExtension(string path)
{
    var result = path;
    do
    {
        path = result;
        result = Path.Combine(
            Path.GetDirectoryName(path),
            Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path));
    }
    while (result != path);
    return result;
}
```

Тогда

```
var s = @"C:\MS.NET\name.txt.txt.txt.txt.txt";
Console.WriteLine(ClearExtension(s));
```

Выведет `C:\MS.NET\name`

Ну и затем можно добавить новое расширение с помощью обычной конкатенации:

```
var r = ClearExtension(s) + ".bat";
Console.WriteLine(r);
```

Выведет `C:\MS.NET\name.bat`

Comment: Тот же `127.0.0.1.txt.log.bat` -> `127`. Так что и здесь свои минусы.

Comment: Ну как бы если `127.0.0.1.txt.log.bat` это полное имя файла, то код работает так как просит тс, если же у нас `127.0.0.1` - это часть пути (отделено бэкслешем от имени файла), то оно останется без изменений

Comment: Имя файла допустим `127.0.0.1`, остальное лишние расширения, на выход надо `127.0.0.1.bat`. Ведь не выдаст же ваш код такое, ибо в стандартных Path методах все банально просто работает - удаляем все с конца, пока не найдем точку, а это значит что простой IP адрес он будет считать за расширение.

Comment: Ну нет, штатно расширением считается только часть начиная с последней точки в строке, это автор предположил, что у него несколько расширений мой код просто удаляет их все

Comment: Бывает, что пишется файл (я беру к примеру лог какого то сервера, который логирует работу указанного IP), изначально он `127.0.0.1.log` - Вроде обычный, с одним расширением, потом бывает что старый лог сервер переименовывает (добавляя дату, цифру или простой `.bak`) и теперь файл у нас такого вида `127.0.0.1.log.bak`. Вот как в таком варианте отработает ваш вариант? Не `127.0.0.1.log`, не `127.0.0.1.log.bak` он успешно отработать не сможет, но `127.0.0.1` ведь типичное имя для файла.

Comment: Ок, в вашей логике есть смысл, но пока пользователи (тс) не требуют дополнительных условий, зачем их придумывать самостоятельно? YAGNI. Ну и да, если формат имени файла заведомо известен, то лучше проверять его регуляркой. А пока нас устраивает функционал штатной библиотеки, надо его использовать. Впрочем, я лишь написал в ответе так как сделал бы это я, тс выберет подходящий ему вариант самостоятельно. :)

Comment: Да я просто вчера всю голову над чем то универсальным сломал, а в итоге получаю минусы. А у вас решение, которое толком не отработает на именах с точкой, но людям гляжу нравится. Но да ладно, будем считать моими тараканами...

Comment: Минус у вас мой, т. ч. все в порядке :D